# Access zip files

Tags: c, linux, zip

How can I access to the contents of a zip file?

I'm trying write a program in C and I want use the libraries used by zip.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check the open source widely used library [ZLIB](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html).
The link provides sample code and the home page provides more information about the libraries, source code, installation and usage.

Answer (score 3):

The [Info-zip project](http://www.info-zip.org/) has code for that.

Answer (score 1):

[Minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html), which is included with [zlib](http://www.zlib.org) is what you need. Look in the 'contribs' directory for the code. There is an example for zip/unzip and is easily included in a project.